# pthread locking not working

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I have a small program which on one server is working correctly with threads showing accurate data, but on other servers shows duplicates.

I have the following code:

```
// Structure
struct words_list {
    char myword[20];
    struct words_list * next;
};
struct myrepl_list {
    char myrepl[20];
    struct myrepl_list * next;
};

struct arg_struct {
    char *word;
    char *repl;
    int t;
};


int max_thread = 1;
// Mutex variables
pthread_mutex_t repl_list;
pthread_mutex_t thrd_list;

struct words_list * first_word = NULL;
struct myrepl_list * first_repl = NULL;

/*
do_process()
*/
void* do_process(void *arguments)
{
    int *res = malloc(sizeof(int));
    struct arg_struct *args = arguments;
    char *word, *repl;
    int t;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thrd_list);
    word = args->word;
    repl = args->repl;
    t = args->t;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thrd_list);
    fprintf(stderr,"(%d) WORD: %s REPL: %s\n",t,word,repl);

//test example of return
    if (strstr(word, repl))
        *res = 1;
    else
        *res = 0;
//
    return res;
}


int main ()
{
    int ex = 0, i = 0;
    char myword[20];
    char myrepl[20];
    struct words_list * curr_word = first_word;
    struct myrepl_list * curr_repl = first_repl;
    struct arg_struct args;
    pthread_t thread_id[MAX_THREADS];

    while(ex == 0)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
        {
            // Get current word and myrepl
            pthread_mutex_lock(&repl_list);
            strncpy(myword,curr_word->myword,sizeof(myword) - 1);
            strncpy(myrepl,curr_repl->myrepl,sizeof(myrepl) - 1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&repl_list);
            args.myword = myword;
            args.myrepl = myrepl;
            args.t = i;

            //start threads
            if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,&do_process,&args) != 0)
            {
                i--;
                fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in creating thread\n" NONE);
            }
            else
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&repl_list);
                if(curr_repl->next == NULL)
                {
                    if(curr_word->next != NULL)
                    {
                        curr_word = curr_word->next;
                        curr_repl = first_repl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ex = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    curr_repl = curr_repl->next;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&repl_list);
            }
        }

        for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
        {
            void *join_result;
            if(pthread_join(thread_id[i],&join_result) != 0)
                fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in joining thread\n" NONE);
            else
            {
                ret = *(int *)join_result;
                free(join_result);
                if(ret == 1)
                {
                    ex = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //code missing
                }
            }
        }
    }//end while
}
```

which shows on one server this output:

```
(0) WORD: test1 REPL: bla0
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla1
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla2
(0) WORD: test1 REPL: bla3
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla4
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla5
(0) WORD: test1 REPL: bla6
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla7
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla8
(0) WORD: test1 REPL: bla9
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla10
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla0
(0) WORD: test2 REPL: bla1
(1) WORD: test2 REPL: bla2
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla3
(0) WORD: test2 REPL: bla4
(1) WORD: test2 REPL: bla5
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla6
```

and on another server shows this:

```
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla2
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla2
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla2
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla1
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla4
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla4
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla6
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla7
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla7
(1) WORD: test1 REPL: bla9
(2) WORD: test1 REPL: bla10
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla10
(1) WORD: test2 REPL: bla1
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla2
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla2
(1) WORD: test2 REPL: bla4
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla3
(2) WORD: test2 REPL: bla3
```

and I also get this at the end, probably because of the break inside the thread loop:

```
Error in joining thread

Error in joining thread

Error in joining thread

Error in joining thread
```

What am I doing wrong here?

***Why on one servers shows correctly the thread number and the rest of the info but on the other shows messed data?***

I tried all day to solve it but no success.

Comment: Way too much code, please simplify.

Comment: it's already simplified, irrelevant parts have been removed

Comment: The source won't compile.

Comment: I removed some parts, maybe during the removal process I omitted some things, but it compiles successfully

Comment: Post **real** code that compiles. You're essentially asking us to fill in the blanks of a program that no longer compiles, and your omissions  could easily be contributing to the very things that are causing the issue. Example, alk points out your dereferencing a NULL pointer. Is *your* copy of the code doing that? how do we know? Bottom line, *post real code* if you want help with this.

Comment: the whole code has over 4k lines. I posted only the pieces of code which are relevant to my question, those 2 functions. I don't get any compilation error or warning with -Wall so I still don't understand why do you need the whole source... Or do you need also the part where I load data in structures and all the main args ? I thought people with experience don't need the basic parts. And besides, I don't wanna post the whole code due leaching

Comment: You don't have to post *all* the code, but posting a *real* subset that, by itself, replicates your specific issue without introducing potential side effects due to the reduction is the goal of an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
strncpy(myword,curr_word->myword,sizeof(myword) - 1);
```

the program dereferences `NULL`, as `curr_word` is `NULL`. This provokes undefiend behaviour, so after this anything can happen.

---

Also be aware that `strncpy()` does not necessarily append a `0`-termination to the destination character array. See `man strncpy` for [details](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strncpy).

Comment: I even replaced while(ex == 0) with while( curr_word != NULL )

Comment: I will try some modifications on the strncpy part